# Dativo superfluo: Meaning of "Me cansé de que me tomes la cerveza"

Tags: gramática, objetos-indirectos, objetos-directos

Recently, I came across a song that went, "**Me cansé de que me tomes la cerveza**..."

What exactly does it mean? Is it "I am tired of you drinking my beer"? Are both **me**'s here what they call dativos superfluos? What purpose does the first **me** serve and how would the sentence mean any different without it?

Comment: I think, that "me" doesn't fits in there and "la" neither.

Comment: Which "me," the first one or the second one?

Comment: @TheLearner Jaime is wrong about "me" (the second one) and "la" not fitting in there. Although "Me cansé de que tomes cerveza" is possible (meaning: I'm fed up with your drinking beer), the sentence you ask means: I'm fed up with your drinking **my** beer (a specific one, more precisely, the one that belongs to me).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case, *tomar* is not synonymous with *beber*, rather with *robar* or *quitar*.  That makes it a bit easier to understand in the context of the song (“La Guitarra” by Los auténticos decadantes):

> Vos
>   Mejor que te afeites
>   Mejor que madures, mejor que labores
>   **Ya me**<sub>(reflexivo)</sub> **cansé de que me**<sub>(indirecto)</sub> **tomes la cerveza** <sub>*(porque no quieres comprártela tú)*</sub>
>   Te voy a dar con la guitarra en la cabeza
>
> Vos
>   Mejor que te afeites
>   Mejor que madures, mejor que labores
>   Ya me cansé de ser tu fuente de dinero
>   Voy a ponerte esa guitarra de sombrero

Comment: I still don't understand the roles played by both "me's" here. For instance, why should cansar be reflexive in this sentence? As for the second part, I understand he is taking my beer. In that case, isn't mi cerveza more intuitive than using an indirect object?

Comment: Cansar requires an object.  In English, the verb *tire* doesn't require an object.  "I tire you", "I tire him", but then "I tire" is directly equivalent to "I tire myself".  In Spanish, because the object must be used, only the "I tire myself" structure is possible.

Comment: @AmitSchandillia as to the beer, no.  This is directly related to the question you just did on body parts.  In Spanish, the indirect object is used in lieu of the possessive in structures like this.  If you took the beer from me, we presume it's mine.  If it's not, but you still took it from me (I was holding onto it for a friend), then you would use "... me tomes su cerveza" where su indicates it belongs to my friend.

Comment: @guifa in this case *tomar* definitely means *to drink*. The song is from Argentina and here *tomar* is almost never used with another meaning. The son lives in his father's house and drinks his father's beer.

Answer (score 1):

Cada *me* tiene un valor diferente: el primero es parte de *cansar* e indica **cambio de estado** (de estar fresco o descansado a estar precisamente cansado). Utilizar los pronombres reflexivos para expresar cambios de estado es una estrategia muy común en español, basta pensar en verbos como *enfermarse, enojarse, quemarse*... El segundo *me* se puede interpretar con un dativo de afectación: la acción de vos tomar cerveza me afecta a mí directamente (en tanto me quedo sin cerveza). Es una construcción bastante coloquial; en un registro más formal probablemente se prefiera decir algo como *Ya me cansé de que te tomés **mi** cerveza*.

Answer (score 1):

*Ya me cansé de que me tomes la cerveza* has two instances of *me*. The first is trivial: it's part of the pronominal verb *cansarse*, which means "to tire, to become tired", so let's leave that alone.

The second *me* can be analyzed as a **dative of harm** construction (*dativus incommodi*). This is a form that has a parallel in the **dative of benefit** you can find in phrases like

> *Me tomé toda la cerveza.*
>   *Nos comimos una pizza.*

I once answered to a question about *reír(se)* and other pronominal verbs that deals with this [mediopassive voice](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/a/19659/14627) form, and that you might find useful.

Let's go back to the lyrics of the song, but suppose (for brevity) that the sentence is just

> *Me tomaste la cerveza*.

That meaning could be translated literally as "You drank *me the beer", or, rephrased correctly, "You took the beer from me and drank it", or simply "You drank my beer", only the former translation is too long and the latter misses the connotation of harm or loss; that's what the pronoun *me* is about. It's as if you could say "You drank the beer from me" in English.

The same meaning can be expressed (from the other side, as it were) as

> *Te tomaste mi cerveza*.

In this case the translation is "You drank my beer", but the inclusion of *te* turns the phrase into a **dative of benefaction**: not only did you drink my beer, but you drank it for your benefit. The two sentences therefore form an opposing pair.

The benefactive construction is standard in Spanish. The dative of harm is common in Argentina and mostly informal.

There's a phrase that worried mothers often say to the pediatrician when their children refuse to eat properly: *El nene no me come.* If you run this past a translator it will come out "The child does not eat me." The meaning, of course, is "The child does not eat *and that affects me.*"