# Why does "reírse" always have reflexive?

Tags: verbos, reflexivos

It seems that reírse ("to laugh") is *always* used with the reflexive.

- Yo *me río*. (I laugh.)
- Él *se rió*. (He laughed.)
- *Nos reíamos* durante toda la película. (We laughed during the entire movie.)

As I understand Spanish verbs, the reflexive can be used (as in this context) to change a transitive verb to an intransitive; i.e. as if the subject is performing the verb on himself/herself/itself.  This makes sense for *reír*, but now it seems that the reflexive is redundant and extraneous.

Seeing how *reírse* is always intransitive anyway, I'm curious:

## Question

> Could *reír* be used without the reflexive, and/or could it be used transitively?  How might that translate to English (if at all)?

Comment: This is a *quasi-reflexive* construction: it has reflexive form, but not really reflexive meaining. In fact, you can say use the verb *reír* in non-reflexive form, though it is unusual and old fashioned. The origin of the quasi-reflexive construction, nevertheless, is beyond my knowledge, so I cannot give a good answer for your question.

Comment: I've added translations to my answer - I'll leave it at that because it's actually answering to more than was asked.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First things first:

1. Yes, *reír* can be used without the "reflexive";
2. No, *reír* cannot be used transitively.

Now on to the details:

The use of the (formally reflexive) pronouns with verbs like *reír* or *comer* has been analyzed as a kind of **[mediopassive voice](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mediopassive_voice)** construction that conveys a sense of action of the subject for the subject's own sake.

Spanish grammar is presented traditionally as having two grammatical voices: active and passive, the latter being expressed [periphrastically](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Periphrasis) by the verb *ser* plus the passive participle of the main verb. There are also phrases like *La puerta se cayó* or *Se rompieron los platos*, which are not exactly reflexive, and can be termed a form of **[middle voice](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voice_(grammar)#Middle)**.

Finally there are phrases where the "reflexive" pronoun is optional, as with *reír* (yes, you can say *Reímos mucho* instead of *Nos reímos mucho*, though the latter is much more common). These are usually of a kind that allow a mediopassive meaning of **benefaction for the subject**. That's why you usually find *reírse* instead of just *reír*, and also why you'll find people saying things like

> *¡Me comí una pizza grande yo solo!*
>   *Tus amigos se tomaron toda la cerveza.*
>   *No te imaginas lo que nos compramos.*
>   *Fue de viaje y se trajo un montón de souvenirs.*

In each of these examples the "reflexive" pronouns could all be removed and the sentences would still be perfectly grammatical, but they would sound either oddly distant or formal or missing the emotional touch that their context demands.

Things are not that clear-cut, of course (middle and mediopassive voice are somewhat blurry categories), but there you have it.

ADDENDA: I realized I didn't reply to the last part of the question, because it seems to be tied to *reír* as transitive verb, which is impossible, but I figure it could be useful to know how one might translate a "self-benefactive" mediopassive phrase of this kind into English. For *reír(se)* this doesn't seem possible. In Spanish the closest thing would be something like

> *Reí para mí.*
>   *Reí para mis adentros.*

which translate as "I laughed [quietly] to myself". This doesn't convey the idea of *reírse* and indeed it may imply exactly the opposite.

For transitive verbs that denote acquisition of goods the emotional expressiveness can be expressed in English, as in Spanish, with a pseudo-reflexive, although in a much more general way:

> *Fui a la tienda y **me compré** el vestido más caro.*
>   "I went to the store and **got myself** the most expensive dress."

Note that there might be a problem translating cases like the following, where the subject does something that benefits themself (emotionally) but that is intended for other people:

> *Se trajo regalos para toda la familia.*
>   *"He got himself gifts for the whole family."

Comment: Curiously the DRAE http://dle.rae.es/?id=VnAMCA7 as its first meaning has it as a transitive verb (if I understand the abbreviations correctly).

Comment: @mdewey Indeed it's marked as transitive, and I don't get it. It says [here](https://es.oxforddictionaries.com/definicion/reir) that in Spain you can say *Nadie le ríe los chistes* but I've never heard something like that and I don't think that usage is common. (I'd say *Nadie se ríe de sus chistes*.)

Comment: Thank you for answering a question I had, how to say "nobody laughs at his jokes".

Comment: @pablodf76 here you say that the pronoun "me" in "comerme una pizza" expresses benefaction for the subject, which is an ethical dative. However, in https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/26171/all-about-datives-or-whats-that-funny-le-or-me-doing-in-there , you say that reflexive pronoun in the same expression indicates a complete consumption (aspectual dative). I can see that the latter implies the former, but I don't think that the other way around is valid (a benefit of eating a pizza does not imply that I have eaten it entirely). Could you please explain better?

Comment: @AlanEvangelista I was going to revise the examples but I'm guessing they're OK in this context. Here as you see I don't speak of datives; that question was answered later and it's better researched. *Comerse una pizza* is no doubt an aspectual dative, and it can be also a dative of interest. It's not an ethical dative (it doesn't show concern or involvement).

Comment: @AlanEvangelista The whole thing about datives is not clear-cut and indeed what I found (and together with the community turned into a canonical answer) is a loose classification that linguists more-or-less agree on. It's not basic grammar and it could be explained in a different way. So far this particular way has been useful as a reference, but we shouldn't try to fit every dative in Spanish into one of those boxes.

Comment: @pablodf76 Thanks! 1) So both meanings of completeness and benefit in "comerse" are valid. IMHO it would be nice to explicitly mention this double meaning of "se" in "comerse" in the canonical answer. 2) I have a hard time sometimes differentiating between dative of interest and ethical dative because their definitions overlap: the former "marks a person benefited, harmed or *generally affected* by the event and the latter "shows a certain interest, concern or *involvement* on the part of the referent". I cannot grasp the difference between "to be generally affected" and "to have involvement".

Comment: @AlanEvangelista That's why I said these things are not hard and fast, like tight boxes. In practice you end up getting the idea. I gather no more than 1 in 10000 Spanish native speakers have a notion of this, yet we manage. It only takes practice and exposure.

Comment: @pablodf76 I'm not sure if I made my second point clear. One thing is having well-clear defined concepts and having a linguistic entity whose meaning may be explained by more than one of those concepts (as the pronoun "se" in "comerse" being explained by the ethical dative or aspectual dative). Another thing is having overlapping concepts. IMHO the generic "generally affected" part in the definition of the dative of interest makes this definition overlap with the definition of the ethical dative. If we define the dative of interest to "it marks a person benefited or harmed by an event", ...

Comment: the confusion is eliminated and this definition would still cover all examples of dative of interest (at least it covers all examples I have seen so far).